# Passing unwrapped values to Text() succeeds but to Link() results in "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Tags: ios, api, swiftui

I'm unwrapping values from an API call to display to the user. Displaying these values as `Text()` works but when I try to display a string value with `Link()` I get an error `Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.

I believe this may be happening because the data from the API call has not yet been written to `result`, which is where I store the structured json data from my API call. But this error only appears when I try to display a `Link()`. When I pass the same exact path to `Text()` instead of `Link()`, there is no error.

I am using `DispatchQueue` and a completion handler in my API call which I believe should allow the API call and data writing to occur in the background, which I thought would help avoid errors like these.

```
struct ResultView: View {
    
    @State var result: NYTSearchResponse?
    
    var body: some View {

       VStack {
          
          //These text results unwrap and display just fine          
          Text(result?.response.docs[0].headline.main ?? "")      
          Text(result?.response.docs[0].abstract ?? "")      
          Text(formatDate(from: result?.response.docs[0].pubDate ?? "")
          
          // Error occurs on this line "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"         
          Link("Read Article", destination: URL(string: "\(result?.response.docs[0].webURL! ?? "")")!)

        }
        .onAppear{
            getData(from: formURL()) { (result) in
                self.result = result
            }
        }
    }
}
```

API call with completion handlers and `DispatchQueue`

```
func getData(from url: String, completion: @escaping (NYTSearchResponse) -> ()) {
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("Error loading data")
            return
        }
        
        do {
            let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(NYTSearchResponse.self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(result)
                }
            
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }    
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Why does this error only appear when I try to form Links and how can I get around this?

Comment: Looks like the problem is with force unwrapping `webURL!`. Did you try adding it to a Text() as well?

Comment: @LuizDias Text() works. When I use Text(result?.response.docs[0].webURL ?? "") there are no errors and the url string displays correctly.

Comment: Hm okay I now see there are a few ! in that line, likely the result of using Xcode's suggested fixes. I'm having trouble keeping all the elements straight. Any tips for how you would format the line?

Comment: Okay I have changed that line to `Link("Read Article", destination: URL(string: "\(result?.response.docs[0].webURL)") ?? "")` and now I am working through a different error `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'URL'` even though `webURL` is defined as a `String?` type in my custom object definition

Comment: Updated the string to `Link("Read Article", destination: URL(string: (\result?.response.docs[0].webURL)) ?? "")` and now getting a strange error on the body `Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please file a bug report`

Comment: I believe this latest error occurs when a line is severely deformed. Can anyone advise the proper formation of this line?

Comment: To clean up your code, create another property `var firstArticle: NYTArticle? { return result?.response.docs.first }` and access that instead. It'll remove a bunch of the repetitive optional chaining here.

Comment: @AdamPro13 Thanks this is a great idea. I'm trying to declare this `var firstArticle: NYTSearchResponse? { return result?.response.docs[0] }` but I am getting an error `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`

Answer (score 0):

A solution that works keeps the forced unwrapping, but has text in the alt string

`Link("Read article", destination: URL(string: result?.response.docs[0].webURL ?? "http://www.nytimes.com")!)`